# Notation in propositional calculus

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm trying to solve some exercises from my text book about mathematical logic. Currently, I'm working on exercises about propositional calculus and I'm having some difficulties with the notation. I understand the problem and I know how to solve it, but I don't know how to write it down formally.

I have the following problem from my text book.

> Let $\{1,...,n\}$ represent the students in a class. Each two students
>   of the class have a preference to work together in a group or not.
>
> 1. Construct for every $n$ a formula $\phi_n$ that is satisfied by the interpretation $I$ iff for each student there exists another
>      student with whom the student does not want to work together in a
>      group.

My idea so far was:
For each pair $i,j$ of students, let $X_{i,j}$ denote a variable with $I(X_{i,j})=1$ iff students $i$ and $j$ want to work together in a group.

I think, I now have to express (here in predicate logic) $\forall i \in \{1,...,n\} \exists j \in \{1,...,n\} : \lnot X_{i,j}$ (i does not want to work with j)

How can I do this?

Comment: To be honest, I think the question (the textbook's question as you state it) is rather badly phrased. Can I ask which book this is?

Comment: @Javiator You say propositional logic but this looks like predicate logic.

Comment: Consider the case $n=3$. Write the formula expressing the fact that for student $1$ there exists another student with whom the student does not want to work together in a group: $\lnot X_{12} \lor \lnot X_{13}$

Comment: The "general" formula for the case $n=3$  will be the conjunction of the three formulas above (for $i=1,2,3$).

Comment: @PeterSmith It's the course book from the professor who teaches the course. It is German, so I had to translate in into English. I shortened some of the question, so it's probably my fault.

Comment: @Bram28 I wrote it in predicate logic just express what I want to formulate in propositional logic.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So would it look like this: $ \bigwedge_{i \in \{1,...,n\}} \bigvee_{j \in \{1,...,n\}, i<j} \lnot X_{i,j} $

Comment: @Javiator Oh wow, that's surprising. OK, sorry for second guessing your question!

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. So it would be something like this:

$$(\neg X_{1,2} \lor \neg X_{1,3} \lor ... \lor \neg X_{1,n}) \land (\neg X_{2,1} \lor \neg X_{2,3} \lor ... \lor \neg X_{2,n}) \land ... \land (\neg X_{n,1} \lor \neg X_{n,2} \lor ... \lor \neg X_{n,n-1})$$